# How do I strip a column/node out of an array in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array and a function that currently prints this output:

> {"player_id":"2"}{"player_id":"31"}{"player_id":"31"}{"player_id":"32"}

I need to strip out the node "player_id" so I am just left with an array of numbers.

This is my current code:

specificCommunity.php:

```
$communityPlayerIds = array();
$communityPlayersIds = $dao->getSpecificCommunity($id)
```

MySQLDao.php

```
public function getSpecificCommunity($id)
{

    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "SELECT community_players.player_id\n"
. "from community_players\n"
. "where community_players.community_id = '".$id."'";

  $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   if(!empty($row)){
      $returnValue[] = $row;
   }
}
}
```

This returns the array back to specificCommunity.php where the code continues:

```
$in_statement = array();
foreach($communityPlayersIds as $player_id) 
{
  $in_statement[] = $player_id->player_id;
  echo json_encode(array($in_statement));
}
```

However this doesn't work and returns:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/specificCommunity.php on line 35
>   [[null]]
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/specificCommunity.php on line 35
>   [[null,null]]
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/specificCommunity.php on line 35
>   [[null,null,null]]
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/sites/q/quasisquest.uk/public_html/KeepScore/specificCommunity.php on line 35
>   [[null,null,null,null]]

Comment: try with `$player_id['player_id']` also use `echo json_encode(array($in_statement));` outside the loop, or the best option is `print_r($communityPlayersIds);` chk this and share the result

Comment: That did it! Cheers

Comment: good to know that, there are few more suggestion which i have converted into answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do that then do it in the code that gets the data from the database, so you create a numerically indexed array in this processing

```
public function getSpecificCommunity($id)
{

    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "SELECT community_players.player_id
            from community_players
            where community_players.community_id = '$id'";

    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
        while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $returnValue[] = $row['player_id'];
        }
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Then you can forget about messing with the result of this function

Comment: nice suggestion, u can also use `json_encode` inside the method.

Comment: @devpro Yup, but if you leave that till after calling this function, then you have a choise to use the array as an array if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code as:

**First**, you need to get the result from an array not from object as:

```
$in_statement[] = $player_id['player_id'];
```

**Second**, You also need to remove `json_encode()` from your loop, no need to use it inside the loop, you can move it outside the loop.

```
echo json_encode($in_statement);
```

**Third**, don't know why are you using array again in `json_encode()` method.

**Fourth**, check your `getSpecificCommunity()` method, you are not returning the value, you need to use:

```
return $returnValue; // at last line, this will return the output
```

**Five**, if `$id` is the user input or session value than you need to prepared statement which help you to prevent your code with SQL Attack.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


public function getSpecificCommunity($id)
{

    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "SELECT community_players.player_id from community_players where community_players.community_id = '$id'";

  $result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   if(!empty($row)){
      $returnValue[] = $row['player_id'];
   }
}


//convert array to json data (As you want)

$data_json=json_encode($returnValue);

//return json data

return $data_json;


}

//call your function

$recieve_data= getSpecificCommunity('31');

// check via var_dump() or print_r
```

WHY YOU GET NOTICE/WARNING IN YOUR CODE ??? Ans.

```
$in_statement = array();
foreach($communityPlayersIds as $player_id) 
{
  $in_statement[] = $player_id->player_id;
  echo json_encode(array($in_statement));
}
```

because $player_id is a element of array insted of object...